# Is Abstract class an example of Abstract data type?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, adt

I'm getting confused by these two. What I learned is that Abstract data type is a mathematical model for data type, where it specifies the objects and the methods to manipulate these objects without specifying the details about the implementation of the objects and methods. Ex: an abstract stack model defines a stack with push and pop operations to insert and delete items to and from the stack. We can implement this in many ways, by using linked lists, arrays or classes.

Now, coming to the definition of abstract class, its a parent class which has one or more methods that doesn't have definition(implementation?) and cannot be instantiated (much like we can't implement an abstract stack as it is, without defining the stack's underlying mechanism through one of the concrete data structures). For ex: if we have an abstract class called Mammal which includes a function called eat(), we don't know how a mammal eats because a mammal is abstract. Although we can define eat() for a cow which is a derived class of mammal. Does this mean that mammal serves as an adt and cow class is an implementation of the mammal adt?

Correct me if I'm wrong in any way. Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: They are different things.   An ADT is a model or a concept that defines how a type behaves (so defines how all operations on it behave).   An abstract class is a type that does not provide definition of at least one of its operations.   An abstract class may be used to provide a representation of an ADT, but is not an ADT.

Comment: ADT are usually represented via interfaces (java) or protocols (swift) in OOPL. C++ doesn't have any, but you have alternatives as pure abstract classes (no definition inside only declarations). Remember, ADT is just a model, so no definition of any thing, just external description of what you can do with.

Answer (score 3):

> *Abstract data type is a mathematical model for data type...*
>
> *Now, coming to the definition of abstract class...*

You need to distinguish between theoretical mathematical models and a practical implementation techniques.

Models are created by people in order to reason about problems easily, in some comprehensible, generalized way.

Meanwhile, the actual code is written in order to work and get the job done.

"Abstract data type" is **a model**. "Abstract class" is **a programming technique** which some programming languages (C++, C#, Java) support on the language level.

"Abstract data type" lets you **think and talk** about the solution of a problem, without overloading your brain with unnecessary (at this moment) implementation details. When you need a FIFO data structure, you say just *"stack"*, but not *"a doubly-linked list with the pointer to the head node and the ability to..."*.

"Abstract class" lets you **write the code** once and then reuse it later (because that is the point of OOP - *code reuse*). When you see that several types have a common interface and functionality - you may create "an abstract class" and put the intersection of their functionality in inside, while still being able to rely on yet unimplemented functions, which will be implemented by some concrete type later. This way, you write the code once and when you need to change it later - it's only one place to make the change in.

**Note:**
Although, in *C++ ISO Standard* (at least in the draft) there is *a note:*

> Note: The abstract class mechanism supports the notion of a general concept,
> such as a shape, of which only more concrete variants, such as circle
> and square, can actually be used.

but it is just a note. The real definition is:

> A class is abstract if it has at least one pure (aka unimplemented) virtual function.

which leads to the obvious constraint:

> no objects of an abstract class can be created except as subobjects of
> a class derived from it

Personally, I like that C++ (unlike C# and Java) doesn't have the keyword "abstract". It only has type inheritance and virtual functions (which may remain unimplemented). This helps you focus on a practical matter: inherit where needed, override where necessary.

In a nutshell, using OOP - be pragmatic.

Answer (score 1):

The term "abstract data type" is not directly related to anything in C++. So `abstract class` is one of the potential implementation strategies to implement abstract data types in the given language. But there are a lot more techniques to do that.

So `abstract base classes` allow you to define a set of derived classes and give you the guarantee that all interfaces ( declarations ) have also an implementation, if not, the compiler throws an error, because you can't get an instance of your class because of the missing method definition.

But you also can use `compile time polymorphism` and related techniques like CRTP to have abstract data types.

So *you* have to decide which features you need and what price you want to pay for it. `Runtime polymorphism` comes with the extra cost of vtable and vtable dispatching but with the benefit of `late binding`. `Compile time polymorphism` comes with the benefit of much better optimizable code with faster execution and less code size. Both give you errors if an interface is not implemented, at minimum at the linker stage.

But abstract data types with polymorphism, independend of runtime or compile time, is not a 1:1 relation. Making things abstract can also be given by simply defining an interface which must be *somewhere* fulfilled.

In a short: Abstract data types is not a directly represented in c++ while abstract base class is a c++ technique.

Comment: less code size for compile time polimorphism? I doubt this. I agree with faster execution. as usual, if "faster" (and less size code, actually) is a real benefit depends on the concrete case you are working on

Comment: @GianPaolo It's not guaranteed, but often the case. Of course, the opposite can happen too.

Comment: @Deduplicator, how compile time polymorphism _often_ leads to less size of resulting code? for a set of n classes each with different T template parameter, the compiler has to emit n times the code needed for a single class. I understand this usually lead to bigger size of resulting code. What am I missing?

Comment: @GianPaolo: The compiler is able to optimze the complete call path which mostly results in smaller and faster code size.

Comment: @GianPaolo: The compiler did not emit n times the generated code, because in case of compile time polymorphism exactly one time the code is generated. If there are multiple instances which uses different template instances, you are right, but even than the optimizer is able to unroll/lineararize the call tree which results typically in smaller/faster code. My *erperience* is that gcc & clang do this nearly perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Abstract class an example of Abstract data type?

Yes, but in C++, abstract classes have become an increasingly rare example of abstract data types, because generic programming is often a superior alternative.

> Ex: an abstract stack model defines a stack with push and pop
>   operations to insert and delete items to and from the stack. We can
>   implement this in many ways, by using linked lists, arrays or classes.

The C++ [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) class template more or less works like this. It has member functions `push` and `pop`, and it's implemented in terms of the `Container` type parameter, which defaults to `std::deque`.

For an implementation with a linked list, you'd type `std::stack<int, std::list<int>>`. However, arrays cannot be used to implement a stack, because a stack can grow and shrink, and arrays have a fixed size.

It's very important to understand that the `std::stack` has absolutely nothing to do with abstract classes or runtime polymorphism. There's not a single virtual function involved.

> Now, coming to the definition of abstract class, its a parent class
>   which has one or more methods that doesn't have
>   definition(implementation?) and cannot be instantiated

Yes, that's precisely the definition of an abstract class in C++.

In theory, such a stack class could look like this:

```
template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    virtual ~Stack() = 0;
    virtual void push(T const& value) = 0;
    virtual T pop() = 0;
};
```

In this example, the element type is still generic, but the implementation of the container is meant to be provided by a concrete derived class. Such container designs are idiomatic in other languages, but not in C++.

> much like we can't implement an abstract stack as it is, without defining the stack's underlying mechanism through one of the concrete data structures

Yes, you couldn't use `std::stack` without providing a container type parameter (but that's impossible anyway, because there's the default `std::deque` parameter), and you cannot instantiate a `Stack<int> my_stack;` either.